# Facebook share button without using UiLifecycleHelper

Tags: android, facebook

I want to implement a share button in each of my activities. The idea is that when you press the share button:

1. if you are logged on it shares some hard coded strings (It is just a test, later i won't use hard coded strings)
2. if you're not logged, it send you to the facebook app login screen and after logged, it shares

I was following the Facebook tutorials, but they all use `UiLifecycleHelper` in which the user should press a Log In button before doing any other action. That is exactly what I do NOT want to do, because of the way the flow works on my app. I only need to post 1 single thing, not to maintain a session alive.

How can I do this?

PD: The reason I want to do it this way is because my app is NOT a social app. It is just a simple app that happens to have a Facebook share button, so you publish into your timeline some text. That's why I don't need maintain a session with `UiLifecycleHelper`